# Twenty Questions - a visual puzzle

Tags: knowledge, visual, story, letters, movies

*"Okay, are you male?"*

"Yes. 19 left."

*"Are you alive?"*

"Well, that's... complicated..."

*"Okay, are you real?"*

"No – 17."

*"17? You're counting the last two separately?"*

"Yes to both. 15."

*"Oh, you git! So you're a fictional male... Are you human?"*

"Good thinking. No – 14."

*"Are you an animal?"*

"No – 13."

*"Are you an alien?"*

"Yes – 12."

*"Are you from Doctor Who?"*

"Going niche early, I see. Nope, not from Doctor Who... 11..."

*"Well, are you from TV in general?"*

"Yeeeesss, I *have* appeared in some TV shows, but I wouldn't focus on that as my primary medium. 10."

*"Okay, so a film then?"*

"That's *better*, but, well... I'll say yes. 9."

*"A series of films then?"*

"Yes, although that's not what I was trying- Never mind – yes. 8."

*"Star Wars? Star Trek? Lord of the Rings?"*

"No, no, and – really? An alien in Lord of the Rings? 5 remaining."

*"Ah yes, forgot that for a moment. Um, is it a recent film series?"*

"Recent is relative, but I would say Yes, recent – 4."

*"Is it the new Star Wars trilogy?"*

"I literally just said no to all of Star Wars – the answer is still No. 3."

*"Ach. Do you talk?"*

"Yes, 2."

*"In recognisable English?"*

"Yup. Last one now."

*"Yikes. Errr... Are you a snappy dresser?"*

"Wow. You panicked there, huh?"

*"Yeah, I'm not very good at this game."*

"You're telling me. That being said, I think – ha – I think technically I have to answer 'Yes' to that one!"

*"It doesn't help much."*

"No, probably not, but you'll find it funny later. Tell you what, I'll give you one last clue – a visual puzzle I prepared earlier. Take a look at this, see what you can find, and maybe with everything else you know about me already you'll be able to find my name. I've literally spelled it out for you..."

> **Who am I?** Note that I am **not** looking for unsupported *guesses* (in the style of the word game), rather the game provides you with background that might help you to support the answer to the visual puzzle. A correct answer will identify who I am and explain the solution to the visual puzzle; a perfect answer will do so with a modified image!

[image: Visual puzzle comprising coloured squares and arrows]
*<sup>Colour-blind-friendly version available [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrrXa.png).</sup>*

Comment: Hot network question of the day, wait and see. 

Comment: I don't think getting HNQed makes a difficult Puzzling question any more likely to get solved quickly. The Puzzling regulars aren't finding Puzzling questions in HNQ, and the people who are finding Puzzling questions in HNQ probably aren't the sort to solve one like this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The most obvious place to start is with

> that pun on "snappy dresser". Crocodiles? Carnivorous plants from *Little Shop of Horrors*? Something to do with photographs? Ah, how about Thanos from the Marvel comics and movies? Certainly *snappy* in one sense. And the Marvel stuff *is* in a whole bunch of movies, but it was in comic books first. (The movies are recent enough that the clue-giver's umming-and-erring about "recent" seems deliberately misleading, but no matter.)

I don't know anything much about these, but

> it turns out that there are *six* "Infinity Stones" and their colours are the six colours in the image! Aha. And each Stone has a name: reality (red), soul (orange), mind (yellow), time (green), space (blue), power (purple). I wonder whether combinations of colours correspond to which names a given letter is in? Why, yes, it looks like it, because it seems that the combinations of colours that appear in the image (including of course black in the corners) are exactly the ones for which there's some letter that occurs in *exactly* those stones' names. For instance, E is in exactly R,G,B,P, and lo, one of the squares in the image has exactly those colours in. There are two letters (N,D) appearing in only the yellow stone's name (note that there are two yellow squares in the image), and 10 letters appearing in *no* stone's name; other than that, each combination of colours determines a unique letter.

So:

> [image]

How, you ask, did I disambiguate in the two places where I did? Well,

> the squares labelled 1..6 happen to spell out THANOS.

And of course

> the arrows of any given colour spell out the names of the individual Stones.